# Sort array, prioritizing some items

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need sort an array, priotizing items from a preordered array, in same order. Example:

```
Input:      [ 5, 4, 7, 2, 3, 9, 8 ]
Preordered: [ 1, 2, 4, 3 ]
```

Basically, the `preordered` array will force `input` array to follow this order, but only if item exists on both. If not exists, will check next index. The items that not exists in `preordered` array will maintain in original order. Continuing example:

```
                 ▼     ▼  ▼         // exists on preordered array
Input:      [ 5, 4, 7, 2, 3, 9, 8 ]

              ▼            // not exists on index array, so ignore it:
Preordered: [ 1, 2, 4, 3 ].intersect(input) => [ 2, 4, 3 ]
```

With that, we can determine that three items on `input` exists on `preordered` array. So this items will come first on result. The others items on `input` will keep original order, but after the initial sort:

```
              ▼  ▼  ▼               // keeping preordered array order
Result:     [ 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8 ] 
                       ▲  ▲  ▲  ▲   // keeping others items original order
```

Note that the preordered will keep original order.

**PS.** I can use `underscore`, if need.

Comment: So nothing needs to be sorted ultimately, just grouping the intersection, prepending them, and appending the leftovers of the input array afterwards?

Comment: Might `Input` and/or `Preordered` have duplicates?

Comment: @depperm I tried before and not worked (I don't remembered the intersection), but on write, it help me to solve my problem -- the replies come first and help me a lot too. But as it can be used for others devs (maybe?), so I posted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
result = _.intersection(Preordered, Input).concat(
    _.difference(Input, Preordered))
```

Comment: Not sure about the downvote, I had the same in mind. At least, this is how the question was described.

Comment: @KimGysen: With 68K rep, georg should know *"Like this?"* is a terrible excuse for an answer.

Comment: I'm not the one that downvoted but I guess that this solution is missing the ordering of the intersection of the preordered/input. I think that the difference isn't ordered but the intersection is

Comment: Guess it's my mistake than

Comment: It worked! The intersection must not be ordered. It need keep original order too. Thanks a lot!